# Firebase auth v9 - AuthCredential.fromJSON() disappeared

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the system I work on, there is a auth-web-app which is used to authenticate a user, serializes credential, and then transfer it by message to another app. The other app receives the credential, parse it, and pass it to its own firebase-auth package to authenticate user inside its process.

[In Firebase v8, `AuthCredential` had a static function `fromJSON()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.AuthCredential#fromjson) which was used by the receiver app of the credential to parse it.

But in Firebase v9, this function has disappeared. There no more `fromJSON()` function in in `AuthCredential`. [There's only a `toJSON()` function.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.authcredential#authcredentialtojson)

How can I parse the json representation into a `AuthCredential` instance with v9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use [`OAuthCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.oauthcredential) class that extends [`AuthCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.authcredential) in `V9`.

```
import { OAuthCredential } from "firebase/auth";

const cred = OAuthCredential.fromJSON('{...}')
```